# Bootstrap Glyphicons will not load in Cloudfront

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, amazon-cloudfront

I have the following:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
```

which displays correctly without cloudfront:

[image: glyph]

When I add in cloudfront:

[image: missing_glyph]

```
Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-09 13:18:07 -0500
```

This path does not exist. How do I get the glyph to show?

Edit:

I found this in the console:

```
Font from origin 'http://XXXXXXXX.cloudfront.net' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myhost.info' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: My first idea was to create a custom "sprites.png" with the images, but I would then need to turn off glyphs in bootstrap somehow. My other thought was to create the directory with /assets/bootstrap, but I don't know what files to put in there.

Comment: So, configure CloudFront to send HTTP CORS headers?

Comment: Looking at the error message I think some header is not forwarded to the origin. Did you configure your CloudFront distribution to forward all headers you need?